# How to install jdk 8 and NetBeans8 ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: edubuntu

I've jdk-8u5-linux-i586.gz and
netbeans-8.0-linux.sh 
On ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I'm tired  try to install someone tell me how in details.

Comment: .`.sh` files can be installed with the command `sudo bash [FILE NAME.sh]`

Comment: @user300200 I've jdk-8u5-linux-i586.tar.gz an oracle jdk

Comment: If you are a biginner follow this article http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/tar-sh-install/

Comment: @user300200 sudo update-alternatives --
install "/usr/bin/java"
"java" "/usr/lib/jvm/
jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1 it says update -alternatives --install needs link name path priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blatantly copied this from the [page where you downloaded](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html#linux) the packages

Installing the Software

```
Type the following command from the directory where you placed the installation file:

    ./<installer-file-name> 

At the Welcome page of the installation wizard, click Next.
At the JUnit License Agreement page, decide if you want to install JUnit and click the appropriate option, click Next.
At the JDK Installation page, specify the directory where to install the JDK and click Next.
At the NetBeans IDE Installation page, do the following:
    Specify the directory for the NetBeans IDE installation.
    Accept the default JDK installation to use with the IDE or specify another JDK location.
Click Next.
Review the Summary page to ensure the software installation locations are correct.
Click Install to begin the installation.
At the Setup Complete page, provide anonymous usage data if desired, and click Finish.
When the installation is complete, you can view the log file, which resides in the following directory: ~/.nbi/log.
```

Note: If you choose to install this bundle into a system-wide location such as /usr/local, you must first login as root to gain the necessary permissions.

Comment: I'm beginner and I need in details I've  jdk-8u5-linux-i586.tar.gz and netbeans 8.0 i586.sh I'm tired .